# Scrapy use css pseudo element in selectors

Tags: python, css, scrapy

I know this can be done with string formatting, etc. after the fact, but I have a variable with a selector ending in:

`.css("::text").extract()`

Which returns the data that happens to be caplitalized.  I'm curious if I can do something like:

`.css("::text-transform: capitalize").extract()`

Using `text-transform` method from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform

I've tried to play around with the syntax, but typically get the following error:

`cssselect.parser.SelectorSyntaxError: Got pseudo-element ::text-transform not at the end of a selector`

I don't know too much about css, but I see theres a lot of formatting methods, etc. so more generally, is it valid to use any of these within ones scrapy selectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you want using scrapy's `.css` method, you can only specify a selector there, what you want is text transformation.
Instead, capitalize a string in python after you retrieve it:

```py
extracted = [t.capitalize() for t in response.css("::text").extract()]
```

Details: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_capitalize.asp

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks for the info, i'll close this out